# LC3: How to JMP to a TRAP instruction? Getting unrecognized opcode/syntax error

Tags: assembly, lc3

**CONTEXT:**

I'm writing a program where the user is requested to input a "1" or "2", that value's ASCII value is added by -49, and depending if the sum is 0 or 1, a string will be printed.

**ERRORS AND CONFLICT:**

*1E:*

`Line 18: Expected register operand, but found 'START' instead`

`Line 23: Expected register operand, but found 'START' instead`

*1C:*

I quickly learned from this error that I cannot JMP to a label. My intuition was that it would just go to the instruction with START (line 4). I wanted this so that at the end of the case instruction, it would start over and ask for another number, however I can only JMP to a register. How can I make this change?

---

*2E:*

`Line 21: Unrecognized opcode or syntax error at or before 'CAS2I'`

`Line 26: Unrecognized opcode or syntax error at or before 'CAS2I'`

*2C:*

I'm really not sure what is wrong with lines 21 and 26. Here they are respectively:

`CAS1I  LEA R1, CAS1S`

`CAS2I  LEA R2, CAS2S`

---

*3E:*

`Line 21: Duplicate label 'START' found with label on line 4`

`Line 26: Duplicate label 'START' found with label on line 4`

*3C:*

These errors throw me off because of the word "duplicate." I only have START written once and while both lines 21 and 26 have the same error, their contents are different. Here they are, respectively:

`CAS2I  LEA R2, CAS2S`

`CAS1S  .STRINGZ "1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100"`

**CODE:**

```
    .ORIG x3000

; INPUT REQUEST: Store input value into R0
START   TRAP x23


; CASE CREATION: Add -49 (R4) to input value (R0)
    ADD R3, R0, R4

; BRANCHES: If R3 = 0, execute Case 1 Instruction. If R3 > 0 (specifically if R3 = 1), execute Case 2 Instruction
    BRz CAS1I
    BRp CAS2I

; BRANCH CASES:

; CASE 1 INSTRUCTION: Load Case 1 String into R1. Print string in R1. Jump to  START (input request).
CAS1I   LEA R1, CAS1S
    TRAP x22
    JMP START

; CASE 2 INSTRUCTION: Load Case 2 String into R2. Print string in R2. Jump to  START (input request).
CAS2I   LEA R2, CAS2S
    TRAP x22
    JMP START

; STRING STORAGE: Store input patterns in Case 1 String and Case 2 String
CAS1S   .STRINGZ "1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n0110\n0011\n1001\n1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100"
CAS2S   .STRINGZ "1100\n1001\n0011\n0110\n1100"

; FILL PROCESS: Put value -49 in address of FN. Load value in FN address (-49) into R4
FN  .FILL #-49
    LD R4, FN

    .END
```

**CONCLUSION:**

I thought I had the right idea for this program, but it seems like I'm missing information to do it properly. Any advice will also be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess, but sometimes code labels require a colon. So try `START:` and `CAS1I:` and such (when defining, not when referencing)

Comment: @Jester I tried adding the colons, but I don't think it did anything. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Use `BRnzp` instead of `JMP`. With that change it assembles fine here. I don't get your other errors.

Comment: @Jester Woah, no way! You're right. Can you please explain how that works?

Comment: That's basically a "branch always" since it lists all possibilities.

Comment: That's genius! Thank you so much!!